# if condition in swift function for optional parameter

Tags: swift, function, optional-parameters

I have a function : myFunction(param1: class?, param2: class?, param3: Int, ...) where the 2 first parameters are optional and the type of them is a custom class.
But sometimes, the class I need to put in these parameters doesn't exist, that's why these parameters are optional. And I can't put 'nil' as value.

So I would like to do something like this :

```
if (param1 !=nil && param2 != nil) {
   myFunction(param1: myClass, param2: myClass, param3: 2, ...)
}
else if (param1 ==nil && param2 == nil) {
   myFunction(param3: 2, ...)
}
else if (param1 !=nil && param2 == nil) {
   myFunction(param1: myClass, param3: 2, ...)
}
else if (param1 ==nil && param2 != nil) {
   myFunction(param2: myClass, param3: Int, ...)
}
```

...

The problem is that, in my function I have more optional parameters so if I need to have a "if" condition for all options, it will be impossible to manage.

So is there a way to put an if condition inside the function parameters ? Example :

```
myFunction(myClass==nil ? <nothing>:param1: myClass, myClass==nil ? <nothing>:param2: myClass, param3: 2, ...)
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Regards,

Comment: `But sometimes, the class I need to put in these parameters doesn't exist, that's why these parameters are optional.` How can you have a class that doesn't exist as a type of a parameter?

Comment: Also, i'm curious what you think nil means, if not `<nothing>`

Comment: you should get clear about classes, types, instances, etc. what are you passing where under what circumstances? Do you really want to pass the *type* `Int` in the last function call?

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear about using your classes as params in the function. You should re-architect them as per the usage. If at all you want to use this function with initial 2 params as optional then  you could do something like this.

```
if let param1 = param1 {
    if let param2 = param2 {
        myFunction(param1: myClass, param2: myClass, param3: 2, ...)
    }else{
        myFunction(param1: myClass, param3: 2, ...)
    }
}else if let param2 = param2 {
    myFunction(param2: myClass, param3: Int, ...)
}else{
   myFunction(param3: 2, ...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to change the architecture or change something

Answer (score 0):

You designed your function to get some parameters as optional, than you should not care about unwrapping when you call the function, you need only to handle this optional params in your function with guard or if let.

```
func myFunction(param1: AnyObject?, param2: AnyObject?, param: AnyObject) {

   guard let firstParam = param1, secondParam = param2 else { return}

   // here use your unwrapped params

}
```

Comment: Oh I understand ! Thanks a lot, I'll try this